# how to send a php variable to jquery in different file and action to the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have two files which are **A.php** and **B.php**

**A.php** is the file that keep a variable that want to send to **B.php**

**A.php code**

```
 $customer = array("name"=>"testname","age"=>"testage");

    echo json_encode($customer);
    exit();
```

**B.php** is the file that contain some juery script

**B.php code**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <?php include '../nesscript.php'; ?>
        <script>
            $.ajax({
                url: "A.php",
                dataType: "json", 
                success: function (data) { 
                    alert(data.name);
                }
            });
        </script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        echo "HELLO";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

when I run the **A.php** file, I got this output

> {"name":"testname","age":"testage"}

And when I run **B.php** file dirrectly, I got the alert box like this.

> testname

So, I suppose that the data is already sent, but what I actually want is when the A.php file has finished then go to the B.php file without data losing

How can I do that? Anyone please.

Comment: Do you want to open A.php first and then go to B.php? And not from B to A? If so, what's the use of this AJAX code in B.php??

Comment: And what do you mean by "when the A.php file has finished "? How are we supposed to know that it has "finished"? Please show your entire code.

Comment: A.php is actually the script file that I want to check something and B.php is like the homepage I want to output by using data from A.php file

Comment: A.php has finished means the data is already sent

Comment: If so, I don't see why you'd need to open A.php. You're supposed to open B.php and get the desired data from A.php and process results accordingly, like you have done. It doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: actually,the fact is,I have login form in another file which action to A.php file (textbox for username and textbox for password) if I login then I will use A.php file to check if username and password are both correct. And then I will use usename and password to pull data of the customer like name,age,phone number etc. and send that data to the B.php file to show output
sorry for confusing you :)

Comment: I just want to know the method how it work and apply it to my project, so I don't use full code